# js regexp exclude certain pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/.*\.js$/
/^app\.js$/
/.*\.test\.js$/
```

Suppose I have above three regex. How can I write a single regexp so that it matches everything that matches the first one but not match the second and third one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^(?!.*\.test\.js$|app\.js$).*\.js$/
```

Quite literally:

- `(?!)` doesn't match
- `|` one or the other
- `.*\.js$` - you still want to match the first
- `^` - I put it at the start